# Why do we say עושה השלום during yamim nora'im?

Tags: halacha, minhag, shemoneh-esrei, kaddish, aseres-yemei-teshuva

I'm struggling to find a reason/meaning behind saying  'עושה השלום' with a 'ה' at the end of amidah and during kaddish for the yamim nora'im period.

I have heard (unverified source) that there is opposition to this practice since it is based on a pasuk, and it is not necessarily desirable to change pesukim.

What is the reason (for those that say it) that עושה השלום is said?

Comment: FYI my shul keeps the "Hamevoreich es amo bashalom" at the end of Sim Shalom and Shalom Rav at the end of Amidah. We also do not add the Hei in the kaddish. The Art Scroll siddur puts them in brackets with the note that there are shuls, like mine, that do not follow the change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [here:](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/Home-Database/default.aspx?pageid=zachreinu__oseh_hashalom__%D7%98_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C)

> Siddur Admur [omitted in Shulchan Aruch]; Shaar Hakavanos 190; Peri
>   Eitz Chaim Shaar R”H 7; Kaf Hachaim 582/15; M”E 582/1 and 22
>
> The reason: The Gematria of Hashalom is the same as Safriel Hamalach
>   which is the angel which writes the Jews in the book of life during
>   Aseres Yimei Teshuvah. [Peri Eitz Chaim ibid brought in Kaf Hachaim
>   ibid; M”E ibid] In however Hagahos Mordechai [Miseches Rosh Hashanah
>   720 he states as follows: Safiriel is the Gematria of Oseh and Oseh is
>   the Gematria of Hashalom. Alternatively this hints to the kindness of
>   Hashem that swerves the judgment to merit in a case that the sins and
>   merits are equal, and the verse states “Maaseh Hatzedaka Shalom”.
>
> Other opinions: Some write that according to the Kabalists one is not
>   to change the dialect in Kaddish and is rather to always say Oseh
>   Shalom as is said during the year. The change is only made by the end
>   of Shemoneh Esrei. [Kaf Hachaim 56/38; Alef Hamagen 582/37]
>
> Custom of Sefaradim: The Sefaradim are accustomed to only recite Oseh
>   Hashalom in Kaddish Tiskabel that follows Shemoneh Esrei. They do not
>   recite it by other Kaddeishim. [Moed Lekol Chaiy 13/69; Piskeiy
>   Teshuvos 582/9; See Yalkut Yosef Moadim p. 26 ]

Answer (score 3):

[Siddur Hagaonim Vhamikubalim - page 55](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22662&st=&pgnum=56) gives the following reasons regarding the end of the Amida.

A: Mateh Moshe 795 - Since this is a time of judgement, and there is no judgement in charity and no charity in judgement the regular Nusach is inappropriate. However by saying Oseh HaShalom we are saying that the place of judgement is peaceful as the verse in Zecharya 8:16 says Emes Umishpat Shalom.

B: "Hashalom" is the same Gematria as "Safriel".

Comment: ....Safriel = ?

Comment: @Gershon Gold, Ushalom isn't the same as HaShalom. Also can you explain the relevance of this gematria?

Comment: @bondonk: I am not a Mukubal and do not know the significance of the Gematria. However it is mentioned as a reason for saying השלום.

Comment: Hashalom is also Gematria of Hoshea, Rofe Cholim, and Chacham Bakshi.